# object not locked by thread before notify()?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to resolve the problem but failed, I see other stack overflow's question problem but failed to resolve

How to resolve the below problem?

> notificationBuilder.notify(notiID , notificationBuilder.build());

```
public class Noti extends AppCompatActivity {

NotificationManager notificationManager;
Boolean isNotiActive=false;
int notiID=33;
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_noti);

   notificationBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Alert")
            .setContentText("new msg")
            .setTicker("Alert new msg");

    Intent intent=new Intent(Noti.this, MoreNoti.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder= TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Noti.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

     notificationBuilder.notify(notiID , notificationBuilder.build());

     isNotiActive=true;

}
```

}

Comment: please post code as text

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the right `notify()`.

Change

```
notificationBuilder.notify(notiID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

to

```
notificationManager.notify(notiID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

`Object#notify()` is a method used in Java to deal with multithreading. That's not what you want.